# how to print a string to console in c++

Tags: c++, console, cout

Im trying to print a string to console in c++ console application.

```
void Divisibility::print(int number, bool divisible)
{
    if(divisible == true)
    {
        cout << number << " is divisible by" << divisibleBy << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << divisiblyBy << endl;
    }
}
```

i have the correct includes etc, this error i believe is just that i simply dont know how to print to console in c++ yet and this i guess isnt the way to do it

EDIT: sorry forgot to mention divisiblyBy is the string

Comment: What doesn't work? How are you invoking this code? What error are you seeing? Help us help you. All you've done is posted one isolated segment of code which (in isolation) appears to be syntactically valid.

Comment: Which OS are you targeting?

Comment: Note that global variables such as `divisibleBy` are not good; you should pass it to the function as a constant reference argument.

Comment: On the whole, that is the correct way to print to `cout` and if `cout` is attached to (going to) the console, it should be correct.  If you are running this from a GUI IDE and it creates a new window which then vanishes, that is actually not directly a problem with the program but rather with the programming environment.  You probably want a space after the `by` in the string literal.

Comment: Have you included `iostream` on the top of your program?

Comment: Make sure you didn't forget "using namespace std" at the top of the program. Try to replace all "cout" to "std:cout" to figure it out.

Comment: If your platform is windows, do you use a conole application?

Comment: @AngryDuck it's not "hate" , they're just trying you help you formulate a more precise question which will help get you the answer you need.

Comment: Yes it is possible and the code you posted is correct assuming `divisiblyBy` is `std::string`.

Comment: I've tried all the answers here and VS still says "'cout': undeclared identifier".

Answer (score 45, accepted):

yes it's possible to print a string to the console.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    string strMytestString("hello world");
    cout << strMytestString;
    return 0;
}
```

stdafx.h isn't pertinent to the solution, everything else is.

Answer (score 14):

All you have to do is add:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;
```

at the top.
(BTW I know this was posted in 2013 but I just wanted to answer)

Comment: Thank you for adding this comment, many people publish incomplete code that does not work so it is useless for beginners due to missing 1 or 2 lines of "include", "using" etc.

Answer (score 6):

> "Visual Studio does not support std::cout as debug tool for non-console applications"
> <sub>- from [Marius Amado-Alves' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16703835/visual-studio-how-can-i-see-cout-output-in-a-non-console-application/19095301#19095301) to "*How can I see cout output in a non-console application?*"</sub>

Which means if you use it, Visual Studio shows nothing in the "output" window (in my case VS2008)

Answer (score 3):

you need to include the needed headers first
which are:

1- `#include<iostream>`, so that you can read and write.
2- `#include<string>`, so that you can use (string) class.
3- `using namespace std`
or
you can just write

```
std::cout
```