# How can I see cout output in a non-console application?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

It seems rather tedious to output to debug window. Where can I find `cout` output if I am writing a non-console information ?

Like:

```
double i = a / b;
cout << b << endl;//I want to check out whether b is zero. It seems the output cannot be found anywhere.
```

Comment: Perhals use a logging framework, such as NLog, that allows you to direct log output to any/all of file, console, viewer app, email and many others?

Comment: I was about to say that, but as alternate suggestions, Poco has one, and I believe Boost does as well. I wouldn't be able to speak from personal experience which are considered best.

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338812/printing-to-the-console-vs-writing-to-a-file-speed

Comment: What is your real problem?  Is it that you want to see the output of `cout` in a non-console application?  Or is it, as indicated in your comment, that you want to see the value of `b`?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Of course it is I want to see the output of cout. I want to see the value of `b` output by `cout`.

Comment: You could write a `stream` that calls `OutputDebugStringA`.  It's not redirecting `cout`, but I believe it will assist you.  See my answer below.

Comment: Regardless of whether an alternate solution can be found for this specific debugging problem, I think it's an interesting question as asked. I'd love to see a real answer.

Comment: P.S. I believe the answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/428976/5987

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To output a string to the debug console, use `OutputDebugStringA`.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

To output variable values to the debug console, using `std::ostringstream`, the send the string to `OutputDebugStringA`.

Excessive output statements will cause the program to severly slow down.  However, it is a good technique to catch things the debugger has a problem with, such as the actual child members when playing with base pointers.

Comment: Only thing about this is OutputDebugStringA is a WINAPI.  Which is fine if you are creating a Windows Console Application, but if you want pure C++ without Windows (yes, even using Visual Studio 2017!), you can't use this one.

Answer (score 119):

The question is very clear. How to use `std::cout` to debug a non-console application in Visual Studio.

The answer is very clear: you cannot. That is, Visual Studio does not support `std::cout` as a debugging tool for non-console applications.

This is a serious limitation of Visual Studio, probably a failure to meet the C++ standard even. I find it very sad to see disinformative "answers" here trying to hide this defect of their precious Visual Studio.

Comment: While this still is a valid point, for those interested in a convenient workaround: have a look at Trevor Hickeys answer down below.

Comment: Please see my answer. I've done it. Actually in the Debug Output window. No separate console window.

Answer (score 36):

For a Windows solution, you can allocate a console, and bind cout/cin to it.  For example:

```
AllocConsole();
freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stderr);
```

Documentation:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: But this opens an extra window. I want the output to be in the Debug Output pane of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 22):

SOLUTION: This answer solves the question and allows you to redirect console output to the Visual Studio Output window.
First we need a class that overrides the default cout string stream:

```
class dbg_stream_for_cout
    : public std::stringbuf
{
public:
    ~dbg_stream_for_cout() { sync(); }
    int sync()
    {
        ::OutputDebugStringA(str().c_str());
        str(std::string()); // Clear the string buffer
        return 0;
    }
};
dbg_stream_for_cout g_DebugStreamFor_cout;
```

Then, somewhere you want to "activate" writing to the VS output window:

```
std::cout.rdbuf(&g_DebugStreamFor_cout); // Redirect std::cout to OutputDebugString!
```

Answer (score 6):

I'd like to give my 2 cents.

Given that the maybe is a VS issue about compliancy with the C++ standard or that we could use `OutputDebugStringA`, if you cannot modify your code base you may like the idea of simply redirect the std::cout to something else, like a file.

So without changing your code base you can do something like suggested here:[How to redirect cin and cout to files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150468/how-to-redirect-cin-and-cout-to-files)

Condensed:

- add the include `#include <fstream>`
- at the beginning of your app, in some init, before logging you can use:

> ```
> std::ofstream out("out.txt");
> std::streambuf *coutbuf = std::cout.rdbuf(); //save old buf
> std::cout.rdbuf(out.rdbuf()); //redirect std::cout to out.txt!
> ```

- the at the end of your app/logging:

> std::cout.rdbuf(coutbuf); //reset to standard output again

Hope this may help someone, Kudos to Nawaz that provided the answer in the other thread.

Comment: I like this answer. Redirecting to a text file has many merits, chiefly it enables logging and saving data.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using cout, create a log file and write anything you want into it.

Edit:
Use this simple code for writing to a log file.

```
ofstream log;
log.open ("log.txt");
log << "Writing this to a file.\n";
log.close();
```

Comment: "Where can I find cout output if I am writing a non-console information ?" this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: *"I want to check out whether b is zero."* -- It solves that problem.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley if I write the exact same question without the comment, it'd get closed as a duplicate of this, and my question wouldn't have been answered.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Well, this question clearly needs some work. The OP's goal is not clear, so I've asked for clarification.  But as it stands, this answer does address the apparent problem the OP is having.  And I wouldn't be one of those close voters.

Comment: @CDT yes it is meant to work at runtime. The only problem is that the variable changes from `log` to `myfile` halfway through the example - it should be consistent.

Answer (score 1):

You can use .Net functions such as System::Diagnostics::Debug::WriteLine("your message"). You can even add a condition to print only during the debug mode and not in the release mode. For example:

```
#ifdef DEBUG   
   System::Diagnostics::Debug::WriteLine("your message");
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, indeed, it's annoying.

Here's how I do it :

```
#define DBOUT( s )            \
{                             \
std::wostringstream os_;    \
   os_ << s;                   \
   OutputDebugStringW( os_.str().c_str() );  \
}
// example :    DBOUT("some text " << some_variable << "   some more text" << some_other_varaible << "\n");
```

Comment: Explaining the code is rather more beneficial than pasting just a code snippet. If you could explain your code by commenting or writing a little about it, it'd be great.